# Retrieve a list of items where an item exists in one of the items lists

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Please excuse the slightly confusing title. I have a model (Project) which contains a list of items (Users).

I would like to retrieve all of the projects, where the current user is a member of the user list for that project.

I've tried:

```
List<Project> _MemberProjects =
                    _Db.Projects.Where(p =>
                         p.Users.Contains(_User)
                    ).ToList();
```

This results in the following error:

```
Unable to create a constant value of type 'Nimble.Models.UserAccount'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
```

**User Model:**

```
public class UserAccount
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Project> Projects{....}
}
```

**Project Model**

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }        
    public string Owner { get; set; }       
    public ICollection<UserAccount> Users{...}
    public ICollection<ProjectGroup> Groups{...}
}
```

Comment: Does your user have and Id that is a Guid, Int or any other primitive type? If yes, lookup the user by comparing Ids.

Comment: @JamesBlond yeah i'll post the user model 1 sec.

Comment: Based on your Model I've added an answer which uses Any() instead of Contains() and compares the INT UserIDs instead of users.

Comment: Does it work? If it does, could you mark the answer as accepted? Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't tried this, but it might work:

```
List<Project> _MemberProjects =
                _Db.Projects.Where(p =>
                     p.Users.Any(u => u.UserID == _User.UserID )
                ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are mixing together Linq (the WHERE clause) and a non-Linq Collection operation (Contains). Try using pure Linq. @JamesBond's answer might work.

Are you querying a database? Then a JOIN might be another solution, but the exact syntax depends on how you are storing the relationship between the two tables.